# How to limit power consumption for amd gpu driver based cards (RX)

Tags: amdgpu-pro, ethereum

Is there a way to limit or control the power consumption for AMD graphics cards (i.e. Radeon RX580) using the [AMDGPU-PRO Driver](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) on linux?

(AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux Version 17.40, Ubuntu 16.04.04, Kernel 4.10.17)